# История наречия "наяву"

Tags: этимология, грамматика, падежи, наречия

Слово *явь* в современном русском языке женского рода, однако в производном наречии *наяву*, как видно, сохранилось падежное окончание *-у*, не свойственное существительным женского рода.

О чем говорит этот факт? Слово *явь* раньше было мужского рода? 
Окончанием формы какого падежа является *-у* — местного?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ранее было слово **яв** (чего там только не было с этим корнем). В этимологическом словаре А. Ситникова сказано следующее:

> **НАЯВУ**. Собств.-р. Образовалось в результате слияния предлога **на** с
>   сущ. **яв** (в форме предл. п. ед. ч.), в XIX в. еще известного. Ср.
>   *явить*.

Подобное объяснение находим в словаре М. Шанского:

> **НАЯВУ**. Искон. Сращение предл.-пад. формы на яву, где яв «бдение» —
>   производное от явить(ся), см.

В словаре Преображенского то же.

Answer (score 0):

В др.русском слово явь заканчивалось на *ъ* - явъ. Т.е. первоначально слово было мужского рода.

Comment: Вы бы источник указали, а то как-то...

Comment: https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%8C.   см. Этимология

Comment: Увы, даже синонимы ж. р. На конце Ѣ — ѦвѢ.