# Одна забота наяву... (Б. Окуджава)

Tags: орфография, лексика, наречия

Из стихотворения "Старый пиджак"(1960 год):

**Одна забота наяву** 
в его усердье (усердьи?) молчаливом, 
чтобы я выглядел счастливым 
в том пиджаке. Пока живу.

**НАЯВУ,** нареч. Не во сне, в действительности, на самом деле. Всё происходило н. Полёты во сне и н.

В современном языке ***наяву*** пишется только слитно, но, очевидно, до реформы 1956 года оно имело и раздельное написание.

**Примеры:**

Вот эту-то душу мы и ощутили **на яву.** [протоиерей Иоанн Сокаль.  Журнал Московской Патриархии, № 04, 1945]

Навстречу бегут выстроившиеся вдоль шоссе чопорные, строгие, ...почти черные кипарисы, **грезящие на яву,** как сомнамбулы, чинары. [Зинаида Рихтер. (1923-1924)]

И вот в стихотворении Окуджавы "забота наяву" ― это забота, **которая очевидна, явно видна**,  здесь нет противопоставления сна и яви. В обычном своем значении наречие  **кажется неверным, надуманным, написанным для рифмы.**

Вопросы:

1) **Можно ли** в этом случае применить авторскую орфографию: **на яву** (сравнить: на виду)?

2) **Когда** было утверждено слитное написание наречия ***наяву*** (в словаре, приложенном к Правилам 1956 года, этого слова нет).

3) Как в современном языке **объясняется** выбор слитного написания? К примеру, [одно из объяснений](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1778753-kak-pishetsja-pravilno-na-javu-ili-najavu.html) мне кажется неубедительным.

О наречии "наяву"

[История наречия "наяву"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439432/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%83)

**Дополнение**

И еще вопрос по авторской орфографии: **в его усердье или в его усердьи?**  Какой вариант бы у автора, так как в современных текстах встречаются оба.

Примечание. В художественной, особенно поэтической, речи допускается написание форм предл. п. существительных сред, рода на -ье (обычно при предлоге в) с окончанием -и, напр.: В молчаньи шел один ты с мыслию великой (П.).

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=38#pp38

Comment: *Какой вариант бы у автора...* Что-то не то с "бы". Может, "был"?

Answer (score 2):

Пишутся слитно наречия, имеющие в своем составе такие существительные или такие именные формы, которые в современном литературном языке не употребляются, среди них и **[наяву](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2058)**.

[Шанский](https://lexicography.online/etymology/shansky/%D0%BD/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%83) пишет:

> **Наяву́**. Искон. Сращение предл.-пад. формы *на яву*, где *яв* «бдение» — производное от *явить(ся)*.

[Учёная дама](http://www.lingling.ru/useful/expert.php?ELEMENT_ID=518):

> Слитное и раздельное написание наречий — одна из самых сложных тем в
>   русской орфографии. Дело в том, что очень ***многие наречия образуются
>   из сочетаний существительных с предлогами. Сначала эти сочетания
>   пишутся раздельно, с течением времени они могут переосмыслиться и
>   начать писаться слитно.*** Во многих случаях не очень легко понять,
>   произошло уже такое переосмысление или нет, поэтому написание многих
>   наречий рекомендуется просто запоминать и в случае затруднений
>   справляться в словаре.

---

> [Вопрос № 238857](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%28%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%83%29%3F)
>
> Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, можно ли слово "на яву" написать
>   раздельно (например, в стихотворении) или всегда нужно писать слитно
>   (наяву)?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Наречие *наяву* всегда пишется слитно.

Но никто не отвечает на вопрос *когда*. А - *с течением времени при переосмыслении*.

---

Ну а что до Окуджавы, то остаётся принять что даёт. Он и дипломированный филолог с опытом преподавания, и авантюрист в обращении со своими текстами и мелодиями.

> ...Получив в 1950 году диплом, два с половиной года работал учителем в
>   Калужской области, на педагогическую работу в школы калужских сел
>   Шамордино и Высокиничи Булата Окуджаву направили по окончании
>   Тбилисского государственного университета.
>
> Также с февраля 1952 до конца 1953 года Окуджава работал учителем
>   русского языка и литературы в калужской школе №5.

Если у него где-то и проскочило раздельное написание, то позже ни разу не возразил против слитного, да и что в нём "концептуального",

а форму *усердья* мог как сам варьировать, так и корректор постараться - бдительность проявить.

Он поёт то в улочках окрестных, то в уличках (прелестная старая форма), то у самых Арбатских ворот, то - хоп! - и Никитских, то на земле этой вечной, то - грешной (а это чтоб народ не скучал, тож с музыкой - и "Троллейбуса", и "Портленда" - всё забота о народе; народ: но мы привыкли! - поэт: ничего, отвыкайте! - и хищно улыбается; небожитель, ему всё можно), а однажды и мне заморочил голову, потому что - смысловое:

["Каждый пишет, как он слышит"? Или "что"? - какой вариант более ранний?](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2821607-kazhdyj-pishet-kak-on-slyshit-ili-chto-kakoj-variant-bolee-rannij.html) -

ну и никто не пришёл со мной поговорить, потому что это всё о том же - о *когда*...

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Меня заинтересовал вопрос о "концептуальности" формы написания.  Вроде бы какая разница - слитно, раздельно, формализм один, а смысла не много.  Но в данном случае слитное написанное  "наяву" мешает пониманию текста, и связано это с современным значением этого слова. НАЯВУ, нареч. Не во сне, в действительности, на самом деле.  А у Окуджавы  забота видна, проявлена,  но при этом она вовсе не связана с противопоставлением  кажущегося и действительного. Окуджава и так сложен и многозначен, а здесь еще 
 орфография подталкивает нас к неверному пониманию текста.